# UVA Online Judge is returning runtime error that I can't find

Tags: java, runtime-error

I've been attempting problem 100 on UVA:

http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=36

However, it keeps telling me that my code has runtime errors that I can't reproduce on my end. It works perfectly fine on my console. I've tried the solutions that other people have, but it's still not working. I even got rid of all public methods as specified.

What other possible reasons are there that I could be getting this issue?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int i =0;
        int j=0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        i = input.nextInt();
        j = input.nextInt();

        while((i!=0)&&(j!=0))
        {
            int tempMax = 0;
            for(int k =i; k <= j; k++){
                if (tempMax<AlgStep(1,k))
                    tempMax=AlgStep(1,k);
            }

            System.out.println(i + " " + j + " " + tempMax);

            i = input.nextInt();
            j = input.nextInt();

        }


    }

    static boolean isEven(int n){
        if(n%2==0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    static boolean isOne(int n){
        if(n==1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    static int AlgStep(int count, int n){

        int newCount;
        int m;

        if(isOne(n))
            return count;
        if(isEven(n)){
            m = n/2;
            newCount = count+1;
        }
        else{
            m = (3*n)+1;
            newCount = count+1;
        }
        return AlgStep(newCount, m);                
    }

}
```

Comment: "I got an error. Please help me." Why do so many people think, they could get help when omitting the error message? Seriously, please tell us what error you get (exception stacktrace, which line, and whatever you feel could make us help you).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I really wish I could but UvA purposely doesn't tell you what error. This is what it tells you: "Your submission with number 13303805 for the problem 100 - The 3n + 1 problem has failed with verdict Runtime error.

This means that the execution of your program didn't finish properly. Remember to always terminate your code with the exit code 0."

Comment: You are right. The error message of UVA is really not informative. Sorry for that. I could only guess that your input is not properly formatted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I did some research to help you.

One finding: UVA Online Judge is very bad in helping you to learn a programming language. It tells you that there is a runtime error, but you cannot see what happened exactly.

To analyze your problem, you must change your program setup a little.

The main program reads data from the standard input stream (aka the console). I assume that you did not input the data in a proper format. I mean, in the same format as UVA does. For having an exact result, you should put the input data into a file. Create a text file with the content from the specification page (the four lines with two integers each).

Change the line

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

to

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
```

Then run your program with an absolute path to your input file as the first program argument. For example "java Main input.txt".

You then will get the following output

```
1 10 20
100 200 125
201 210 89
900 1000 174
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at Main.main(Main.java:29)
```

The problem is in the line

```
i = input.nextInt();
```

which is inside the loop. Here you are always reading the next integer, regardless whether the input file has one or not. See the anser of Tony_craft. You have to take care of that.

Comment: You wrote "The main program reads data from the standard input stream (aka the console)". Standard input is by default the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the specifications of the problem it never says the input will finish with 0 values, so you will have a null pointer exception or something like that when you try to read more numbers than appear in the file. I recommend you to use `input.hasNext()` anywhere.

Comment: Sometimes I explain myself really bad. If you need an explanation of something in my answer just tell me